# Pagination datatables on right

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, datatables

I'm trying to make datatables `pagination float`. I don't know how, so i try to search it from google and i get this :

```
var myTable = $("#myTable").dataTable({
 "sDom": '<"row view-filter"<"col-sm-12"<"pull-right"f><"clearfix">>>t<"row view-pager"<"col-sm-12"<"text-center"ip>>>'
 });
```

with that script i get this

[image]

I'm using `<div class="box-body table-responsive></div>` so i can scroll it. So my question is how can i make the pagination stay in right following the scroll. Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: do you want add css for #mytable by using jquery

Comment: yes i want, why not ?

Comment: or try to use style="float:right" in your jquery

Comment: you are meaning that when you scroll horizontally, the paging disappears, right?

Comment: @naveen yeah, that what i mean

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you want.

```
 $('#example').dataTable( {
      "scrollX": true
    } );
```

You can use  https://datatables.net/reference/option/scrollX

Answer (score 0):

Pagination is by default on right side ,

just add css and js on the page ,
give id to table and use that id in jquery

like ,

```
 <table id="example1">
```

then code will be in script tags

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('#example1').DataTable({

   });
});
```

Comment: can you give me an example?